# How to get JComboBoxes that are high enough for touchscreen selection

Tags: java

I have a touchscreen interface that I have adjusted the tab, button, and scrollsize but I am uncertain if it is possible to make JComboBox easier to select individual items. Is there someplace that I can find a list of all the UIManager attributes that can be changed with put?

Comment: Yup! Edited to reflect actual class name. Ever have one of those days?

Comment: "Ever have one of those days?"  Only 'every other day'. ;)

Comment: I think of the chance of me forgetting the word chance increases rapidly as the end of the day draws near.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you're looking for:

http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/

You may need to set your own ListCellRenderer. It doesn't seem to have anything to change the default height.

Comment: Are the selections of a JComboBox covered by list cell renderer? Will that change the size of all my lists. I will give it a try.

Comment: Yeah. If you set a custom ListCellRender you'll be set. Actually, all you really need to do is extend DefaultListCellRenderer which extends JLabel itself, and set the preferred size on the label before returing it. (You will however, need to set that renderer on all of your lists)

Comment: Killer. Muchos gracias, amigo.